# Flume: Kafka Sink and control characters

Tags: character, controls, apache-kafka, flume, sink

I am trying to use Flume 1.6 to read my source files (pipe delimited text files) and feed them to kafka.

All of the plumbing seems to work fine and all the records are getting in to kafka successfully. However, Flume seems to add NUL and STX control characters at the start of each data line.

This is bit if an issue for me because eventually I am streaming all the data from Kafka to Amazon S3 and finally into Amazon Redshift. Owing to these control characters, my data loads to Redshift (COPY command) are failing.

I have spent considerable time researching this problem on internet but no luck so far. Can I somehow instruct Flume not to add these characters in my source data?

My Flume configuration is given below. I have tried both "exec" and "spoolDir" sources and it changed nothing.

```
kafka-agent.channels=ch1

kafka-agent.channels.ch1.type=org.apache.flume.channel.kafka.KafkaChannel
kafka-agent.channels.ch1.brokerList=localhost:9092
kafka-agent.channels.ch1.topic=call-center-dimension
kafka-agent.channels.ch1.zookeeperConnect=localhost:2181
kafka-agent.channels.ch1.capacity=10000
kafka-agent.channels.ch1.transactionCapacity=10000
kafka-agent.channels.ch1.parseAsFlumeEvent = true
kafka-agent.channels.ch1.kafka.serializer.class=kafka.serializer.DefaultEncoder

kafka-agent.sources=tail

#kafka-agent.sources.tail.type=spooldir
#kafka-agent.sources.tail.channels=ch1
#kafka-agent.sources.tail.spoolDir=/home/ec2-user/flumespool
#kafka-agent.sources.tail.fileHeader=false


kafka-agent.sources.tail.type=exec
kafka-agent.sources.tail.channels=ch1
kafka-agent.sources.tail.shell=/bin/bash -c
kafka-agent.sources.tail.command=cat /tmp/call_center_dimension_1.out

kafka-agent.sinks=sink1
kafka-agent.sinks.sink1.type=org.apache.flume.sink.kafka.KafkaSink
kafka-agent.sinks.sink1.brokerList=localhost:9092
kafka-agent.sinks.sink1.topic=kafka
kafka-agent.sinks.sink1.channel=ch1
kafka-agent.sinks.sink1.batchSize=5
kafka-agent.sinks.sink1.kafka.serializer.class=kafka.serializer.StringEncoder
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks
Pravesh

Answer (score 0):

Just to close the loop.

Spent a lot of time on this. Also played around idea using regex_replace interceptor to remove control characters, but no luck.

Eventually ended up evaluating and using Apache Nifi. Wonderful tool, with easy set up and fast implementation. I am able to read data from files and push to Kafka Topics using Nifi and it keeps data clean and complete.

Thanks,
Pravesh

Answer (score 0):

Try using the DataStream fileType of your Hdfs file:

kafka-agent.sinks.sink1.hdfs.fileType = DataStream